# What's wrong with health and damage system

Tags: javascript

I'm not exactly the best at coding and I'm trying to work on a game. I've been working on a system to make it so that the player will take damage from attacks but it doesn't seem to work. Right now I'm practicing the health system on Codehs so I can figure out what the issue is. I'm using the JavaScript Console code. The problem is that whenever the player takes damage and I ask them to take it again, the health resets back to 100. I'm including the code that I'm using for this if that helps. Thank you and I hope that someone can help. This code is just so I can get the health system down, it isn't the main code for the game.

```
var Health = 100;
var damage = Randomizer.nextInt(1, 20);
var health = Health - damage;
var crit = Randomizer.nextInt(10, 30);
var dead = Health <= 0;
var rt = Health - crit;
//rt = Round two health

function start(){
    var go = readLine("Take Damage? ");
    if(go == "yes"){
        println("You take " + damage + " Damage!");
        println("Health: " + health);
    }else if(go == "no"){
        println("Nice try! ");
        println("You take " + crit + " Damage!");
        println("Health: " + (Health - crit));
        var rt = Health - crit;
        println(rt);
    }
    var rot = readLine("Take Damage? ");
    if(rot == "yes"){
        println("You take " + damage + " Damage!");
        println("Health: " + health);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that Java and JavaScript are entirely different languages - I've edited the tag for you. Your code would be much more readable if you would indent it though.

Comment: `var health = Health - damage;` This line only gets executed once, on initialization. I believe you want to modify `Health` each time the `start` function is called. For example: `Health -= crit;`

Comment: You mention `JavaScript Console code` but also `Randomizer.nextInt` (from your code) is a java library if I am not mistaken and `println` is also a built in Java method. Maybe you mean you are writing a `Java console app`? Should your statement and tag be updated to `Java`?

Comment: I edited the tag and question to `Java`. Revert back if you need to but then please also update the code so it is javascript and not java.

Comment: @Igor: This doesn't look like any Java I've ever seen. Methods in Java aren't declared using `function`, nor can you just use methods like `println` and `readLine` like this.

Comment: @Igor: `Randomizer` isn't a Java class in the normal class library either.

Comment: @Igor: No Java here! Have a look at the String content checks.

Comment: @JonSkeet - when I searched for `Random.nextInt` I came across https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-random-nextint-java/ but nothing for javascript which is why I assumed it was java.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Ill revert my change.